# Showing changes across projects

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have two projects within my solution. What I want to do is when a property within Class1 (Project 1) changes I want to run a method within Project 2.

How can this be done.

Comment: Please explain how the objects you wish to connect are created? The problem comes down to how to get at a specific instance of Class 1 within another class in Project 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). Make `Class1` implement that interface and raise the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event when the property is changed. In Project 2, subscribe to this event and execute your method, when the event is raised.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this - any chance of an example

Comment: You will get plenty on SO or on the net in general when searching.

Comment: yeah I have googled but dont seem to understand. Can get a listener event working within a project but not across projects.

Comment: I have implemented the INotifyChanged on to the Class1 that is all ok. I create a Listener class within Project 2. Now I cant get it to run the Listener class unless i call it from within project 2 - ListenerClass l = new ListenerClass(PassedParameter);

Comment: Well, you could put it in a static class, but I am not so sure, if this is a good idea. But as I have no clue, what you are trying to do...